# Import() factory

Tags: javascript, meteor, code-splitting

I'm using ES6 code splitting in my app. Works great! But, I'm not a fan of using a lot of boilerplate code.

This is probably a newbie question, but can someone explain to me why this works:

```
export const Router = () => {
  return (
    <ReactRouter history={Context.Router}>
      <Route path={"/"}
             getComponent={(location, cb) => {
               import('/imports/modules/companies/index')
                 .then(module => {
                   cb(null, module.default.Component)
                 });
             }} />
    </ReactRouter>
   );
}
```

But the following DOES NOT WORK:

```
function getModuleComponent(name) {
  return (location, cb) => {
    import(`/imports/modules/${name}/index`)
      .then(module => {
        cb(null, module.default.Component)
      });
  }
}

export const Router = () => {
  return (
    <ReactRouter history={Context.Router}>
      <Route path={"/"}
             getComponent={getModuleComponent('companies')} />
    </ReactRouter>
   );
}
```

In fact, I'll get an error:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot find module '/imports/modules/companies/index'

...which tells me that I'm trying to import the right file. But for some reason import() can't "find" it.

Note that the module named in the exception is precisely the same string used in the first example. So, imports() is being called with exactly the same parameters in exactly the same environment both times. But the second one throws an exception while the first one does not.

Also, though it seems unlikely to me that this is the cause, I should note that I'm experiencing this under the Meteor (v1.6) environment.

Comment: Does the typo in this line: `getComponent={getModuleComponent('companies'}` exist in your actual code? There is a paranthesee missing after `'companies'`.

Comment: No. But good catch. Code runs fine - in both instances. The non-working one gets to the imports() statement just fine (which wouldn't have happened with the error you noted). I just get the noted exception. I've updated the example.

Comment: OK, one more question. Why are you importing `/imports/modules/app/index` in the first example, and `/imports/modules/companies/index` in the second?

Comment: Cut-and-paste error... And another great catch by you. My current code base is now loading EVERY router-based module using the working method (shown above). And I had tried converting only one of them to the alternative (shown). I've literally tried it with precisely the same module name. (E.g. when I replaced the "companies" code from one alternative to the next.)

Comment: Can you try doing `getModuleComponent.call(this, 'companies')`?

Comment: Of course! Thank you for your interest. If I just add this prior to rendering my Router, the call does not generate and error. But, even I would expect that since; when called this way, the JS module isn't actually imported. If I do this `<Route path={'/companies'} getComponent={getModuleComponent.call(this, 'companies')}/>` (which is probably what you meant), I get the same uncaught error (in promise). "Cannot find module..."

Comment: Yes, I meant `<Route path={'/companies'} getComponent={getModuleComponent.call(this, 'companies')}/>`, sorry for the unclear statement.

Comment: The only other thing that I can think of to try is: `<Route path={'/companies'} getComponent={getModuleComponent.call(this, 'companies').bind(this)}/>`, but that "shouldn't" affect it.